# SQLAlchemy, programmatically check argument

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I want to programmatically check a variable to see if it is one of several allowed strings. I can also add a check constraint in the sql code, but I don't really want to do that. I know I can access arguments passed into SQLAlchemy objects via `kwargs`. What is the best what to assert that a passed in argument is allowed?

```
class Attend(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'attend'
  uid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.uid'), primary_key=True)
  gid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('group.gid'), primary_key=True)
  # assert(user_role in GroupRoles.roles) -- want to do something like this
  user_role = db.Column(db.String)
  user = db.relationship('User', back_populates='registered_groups')
  group = db.relationship('Group', back_populates='registered_users')
```

Comment: You can use the enum type instead of the `String` column type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to validate a particular column *when it's assigned in Python* (including in the default constructor), you can use the [`validates`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_attributes.html#sqlalchemy.orm.validates) decorator:

```
class Attend(db.Model):
    ...
    @validates("user_role"):
    def _validate_user_role(self, key, value):
        assert(user_role in GroupRoles.roles)
        return value
```

Your particular use case, however, seems to fit an enum better:

```
user_role = db.Column(db.Enum(*GroupRoles.roles))
```

This produces server-side checks that the value is valid. In SQLAlchemy 1.1 (currently unreleased), this also performs Python-side checks, obviating the need for the `_validate_user_role` function above (still necessary in SQLAlchemy 1.0 and before).